# C# WCF service | Word document

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, ms-word, office-interop

I have a AngularJS app which is consuming my WCF rest services.

I would like to have a method in my service that create a Word document.

I try it using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

I found that it won't work because it's on the server-side...

Do you have any idea how I can create a word document in my WCF service ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is To install MS Word on your server (but it's not a good practice).

Another way is to Use Open XML:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb735940%28v=office.12%29.aspx

Comment: Open XML seems to meet what I need to do.
Do you know if it's possible to fill a Word Template with Open XML ?

Answer (score 0):

Installation of Word application is one way but it is always disallowed to install application on server environment.

Second and best solution will be via OpenXML which is the way internally MS-office Word/Excel documents get interpreted.
More info

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd440953(v=office.12).aspx